# asp.net background is not appearing in the browser

Tags: asp.net

I just start making web site in asp.net using microsoft visual studio 2008. I have called a css file and make a background image in one of my div in header. The problem is that that background image loads in the design part of the microsoft visual studio but does not loads in the web browser. I am not getting type of design  what i want. Should i have to add anything extra with ?

Comment: supply with markup and css so it's easier to see what you have done right and wrong.

Comment: the css file is
.style2
{
 background-image:url('D:\WebSite2\header_design\header_design\Resources\header_bg_2.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
   
 And the markup code is
<div class="style2"  align="center" style="height: 100px"  ></div>

These code shows background in visual studio 2008 but not in the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
{background-image:url('header_‌​bg_2.jpg'); background-repeat:repeat-x;}
```

Try this.